# How can Magikarp die?

Tags: magikarp-jump

Some random events in Magikarp Jump that can cause your Magikarp to die, such as getting caught by a Pidgeoto while jumping for a berry in a tree.

After seeing my last Magikarp's life tragically cut short, I'm paranoid about random events killing my next Magikarp.

**What are all the ways Magikarp can die in Magikarp Jump?**

Comment: As a general rule, I avoid doing anything after the game asks me a second time if I want to do something. The berry in the tree is the perfect example.

Comment: I only avoid them if I've waited the 90min for Pikachu/Piplup/Training/League to reset. Otherwise I figured if the Magikarp dies not much was lost.

Comment: @Coronus has the right of it - that's actually a deliberate tell. A double-confirm means you're risking Magikarp's life. A single-confirm means you'll suffer a minor drawback but nothing so serious.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are several events that cause your Magikarp to "retire". Not all of these involve Magikarp actually dying, but either way they force you to get a new Magikarp to train. Taken from [this list](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Pok%C3%A9mon:_Magikarp_Jump#Random_encounter_events), the events that force your Magikarp to retire are as follows, with the bolded events ending in Magikarps untimely demise:

- **Is it Treasure?**: You find a Pokeball on the ground. When you go to pick it up, either its filled with many coins or it's a Voltorb that will self-destruct.
- **Out of Nowhere**: You come across a tree with fruit. If Magikarp jumps up to grab a fruit, it will either get a massive JP boost or it'll get snatched in mid-air by a Pidgeotto.
- Macho Karp: After losing a match, a scientist will come up and ask for help in an experiment. Magikarp with either gain +1 max level, or it'll evolve into Gyarados.
- **Hop, Skip, Whump!**: If you scroll your screen to the top of the feeding pond and tap on Magikarp, it will jump out of the water. Do this enough times, and a Pidgeotto will grab it for dinner.
- Adios, Gyarados!: If you tap on Magikarp enough times while it's in the feeding pond, the Everstone it's holding will break. Once it reaches level 20, it will evolve into Gyarados.

Comment: Possibly worth noting that [Serebii's event guide](https://www.serebii.net/magikarpjump/events.shtml) lists the chance of the first three of these events ending your run at around 1/3

Comment: Also worth noting is that "Hop, Skip, Whump!" and "Adios, Gyarados!" can only be triggered once each, and in fact you should do them for game completion (Event Dex).